# How to reference a subform in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, subform

In my MS Access application, I am using a form which contains only two controls - a textbox and a command button. This form is named as `HEADER FORM`.

`HEADER FORM` is used as a subform in header section of various other forms.

What I want to do is that whenever a particular form loads, I want to fill details in the textbox of the `HEADER FORM` (that will be name of the person who has logged in. The same would be clear from the picture below).

I am trying to call a global subroutine named `updateHeader` in form load event of all the forms.

```
Public Sub updateHeader()
    Me![HEADER FORM].Form.txtHeaderName.Value = strPerson
End Sub
```

Following is the picture showing `HEADER FORM` in Design View and the same being used as a subform in a login form.

[image]

I tried various other options but am not able to come out with the correct way to reference the form. Am I doing something wrong fundamentally?

The error that I am seeing is invalid use of `Me` keyword. 
Also, my `updateHeader` subroutine is a global subroutin which is called from Form_Load event of all the forms.

Comment: Looks correct ... what error are you seeing?

Comment: @dbaseman: I have added the details in the question itself so that all the related information remain together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `updateHeader()` procedure is contained in a standard module, that would explain the complaint about the `Me` keyword ... it's not valid in a standard module.

In a form module, `Me` means "this form".

You could change the procedure declaration to accept a reference to a form.

```
Public Sub updateHeader(ByRef TheForm As Form)
    ' Me![HEADER FORM].Form.txtHeaderName.Value = strPerson
    TheForm![HEADER FORM].Form.txtHeaderName = strPerson
End Sub
```

`.Value` is the default property and therefore not needed here, so I left it out.  But it won't hurt to add it back if you prefer.

You can then call the procedure from the parent form, and pass the procedure a reference to itself (the parent form).

```
updateHeader Me
```

Answer (score 1):

I got these "syntax versions" from Wiley.Microsoft.Office.Access.2007.Bible:
When referencing subform controls:

**Forms![FormName]![SubformName].Form![ControlName]**

When using/referencing subforms within subforms, use the following syntax:
**Forms![FormName]![SubformName].Form![SubSubformName].Form.[ControlName]**